# Add clear button in frontend calendar button panel

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.4, datepicker, calendar, component

I am trying to add a clear button in the jquery datetimepicker widget using the below code.

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
               var holidaysarray = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.holidaysarray;
            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    var options = {
                             beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var formateddatestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [ holidaysarray.indexOf(formateddatestring) == -1 ];
                            },
                            beforeShow: function (input) { 
                                this.dpClearButton(input);    

                            },
                        };

                    $el.datetimepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                },
                dpClearButton:function(input){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    var buttonPane = $(input)
                    .datepicker("widget")
                    .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

                    $("<button>", {
                        text: "Clear",
                        click: function () { jQuery.datepicker._clearDate(input); }
                    }).appendTo(buttonPane).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
                }, 1);
                }
            };

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

I have added `dpClearButton` function but when run it give me error in console like `Uncaught TypeError: this.dpClearButton is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

This is expected behaviour in JS because the context of `this` has changed.

When you declare a function as part of an object the context of `this` switches to be the object itself, this example I've just created in the console should explain:

[image]

First of all I log `this` which is the Window object.

Then I create an object that contains a function which console logs `this`, you'll notice when I run that `this` is now actually set to the `testObject` object I created.

### Solution

To workaround this you can store the previous context of `this` before it gets changed.

To do so add this to the first line of your `init` function:

```
var self = this;
```

Then change your function call to be:

```
self.dpClearButton(input);
```

Comment: added `var self = this;` in `init` function but now i am getting `Cannot read property 'dpClearButton' of undefined`

Comment: If `self` isn't defined then you must have declared it in the wrong place, can you send your updated code please?

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/u10rc46n/

Comment: also i am getting issue for `required`.on first load it validate but when i select day and clear it with button from panel it never validate again.

Comment: Your problem looks to be you declared the `self` variable as a jQuery object, it should be `var self = this;`

Comment: tried same but was not working